# The most efficient way to select aggregated data across the same column using different criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that I'm joining to that I need data from under two different criteria. The query currently looks something like (table names/column names obfuscated):

```
SELECT s.id, r.last_date, r.last_automatic_date,
FROM servers s
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT rb_standard.sid, MAX(log_datetime) as last_date, rb_auto.last_automatic_date
    FROM ruby rb_standard
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT sid, MAX(log_datetime) as last_automatic_date
        FROM ruby rb_auto
        WHERE SUBSTRING(upload_string, 3, 1) = '2'
        GROUP BY sid
    ) rb_auto ON rb_auto.sid = rb_standard.sid
    GROUP BY sid, rb_auto.last_automatic_date
) r ON r.sid = s.id
```

This is relatively speedy, and does what I want. It's not very expandable, however, and it's not very clear as to what it's trying to accomplish. Compare that to an older, much slower version of the query:

```
SELECT s.id,
    (SELECT MAX(log_datetime)
    FROM ruby 
    WHERE sid = s.id 
    GROUP BY sid
) AS last_date,
    (SELECT MAX(log_datetime) 
    FROM ruby
    WHERE sid = s.id AND 
        SUBSTRING(upload_string, 3, 1) = '2'
    GROUP BY sid
) AS last_automatic_date
FROM servers s
```

This is a good deal more simplistic, but is (expectedly) slow. I expect there to be a better solution than either of these, but I'm not seeing it.

The exact question that I'm trying to ask is, what's the most efficient way (from a processing speed perspective) of selecting from a table where the maximum value is desired from a given datetime column, but that value likely changes under different criteria... and the maximum value under those criteria should also be returned in the result set?

P.S. This is using the latest version of MySQL, so there is access to newer features like window functions.

Comment: add   a proper data sample and the expected  result and your table schema too

Comment: For posterity, should I still add example data/result sets/schema? And if so, should it be an edit to the question itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want *conditional aggregation* to combine both aggregates into one:

```
SELECT s.id, r.last_date, r.last_automatic_date,
FROM servers s
LEFT JOIN 
 (
    SELECT rb_standard.sid, MAX(log_datetime) as last_date, 
        -- compare a string to a string ('2'), not a numeric value (2) to avoid unneccessary typecasts
        MAX(case when SUBSTRING(upload_string, 3, 1) = '2' then log_datetime end) as last_automatic_date
    FROM ruby rb_standard
    GROUP BY sid
) r ON r.sid = s.id
```

Comment: That's a great point about unnecessary type castings, I didn't catch that.

Comment: Also, I won't lie, I didn't realize that conditional aggregation was a feature of SQL, at least not inside of an aggregation function. That's extremely helpful to know for the future! Marking this as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The first query-->is optimized for getting data from all of the records while the second query-> the select in a select is optimized for getting the first few rows as fast as possible.

If you are batch processing ie using the output of these rows to process and update data then i would use option 1

If you are a web-page which aims to show the first few records as quickly as possible then use the second option with a pagination query.

By the way if you were using oracle there is an optimization available even further for select in a select called. Scalar Subquery Caching.

But in your case the existing query can be modified to perform better using the solution provided by @dnoeth.